# How to insert conditional page break before a heading?

Tags: ms-word

I am using Microsoft Word 2010. I need to be able to insert a conditional page-break when starting a new heading based upon the space remaining on the current page.

For example, if there is more than four inches of page space remaining, it should start the heading right there otherwise if the space is less than that, the heading should start from the next page.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A page break can be added to the document in the following way:

```
string pageBreak = "\xC";
```

or by `string pageBreak= "\f";`

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How do I use this?

Comment: How to you insert text to Word? Have you opened Word programmatically already?

Comment: No I don't know how to open word programmatically. Right now I'm using word formatting styles. There is an option in the paragraph style editor which allows the heading to start on a new page, but I have found no way to perform any sort of conditional control.

Comment: OK some googling got me to understand what you are saying. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Mind sharing what it was that you did?

Comment: @Superdooperhero, Sure: Lie insert a line break is done by `\n`, insert a page break is done by `\f`. Any other help?

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer when no one actually explains how to insert these strings in the document. I have tried Insert Field and adding Field Codes, but it does not work. Using Office 2011 and Office 2016.

Comment: @ oligofren , Try `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection selection = wordApp.Selection;   selection.TypeText("\f");`